# Cannot delete partition in Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-10, partitioning

I have a Linux partition that I want to delete. I want to then transfer the free space to the Windows partition. I am using Windows. I try and delete it from the Disk Management tool and it hangs. If I then close the program using Task Manager and attempt to reopen it, it hangs on the message "connecting to virtual service" as also reported [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems-and-Recovery/Disk-Management-hangs-with-message-quot-connecting-to/td-p/5899137). I can follow the instructions there to kill the process and get the disks listing again, but if I try and delete again then it's the same result.

I also tried to delete on the command line using `diskpart` but it has the same effect. Just hangs.

The Linux operating system is probably inoperable at this point, for what it's worth. I copied some data to it using Ext2FSD which causes the Ubuntu not to boot, as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848125/recover-ubuntu-installation-after-ext2fsd-installation). I am prepared to just bail on the attempt to recover it, and delete it so I can reclaim the space in Windwos, but I cannot.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Windows Disk Manager is not able to manage linux partition type like ext or swap.</s> To manage these partitions try to use software like [EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/) or [GParted](http://gparted.org/).

Personally i prefer GParted because it can be use as live CD/USB and no need any installation.

**Boot on GParted**

1. Download GParted [here](http://gparted.org/).
2. Create a live USB using software like [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).
3. Reboot on bios to select USB drive for the next boot.

**Using GParted**

> Note : in GParted modifications are not effective until you press <kbd>Apply</kbd> button

At first boot you will see a window like :

[image]

Right click on partition you want to delete. When you delete a partiton, memory become unallocated. When memory is unallocated you wan use <kbd>Resize/Move</kbd> feature on Windows partition to extand it.

Apply settings using <kbd>Apply</kbd> button and reboot to Windows.

Comment: “Windows Disk Manager is not able to manage linux partition type like ext or swap.” – That’s not entirely true. You can still see and delete them from Disk Management or `diskpart`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i will correct the post.